snapshot vs. latexrelease
Reading this article by Barbara Beeton I discovered snapshot package. As a programmer, I immediately associated it to requirements.txt in Python. Then in another article by Frank Mittelbach I discovered latexrelease. Now I'm bit confused! Because it seems that these two packages have the same purpose.
In particular reading snapshot documentation you can read

This could be useful for someone wanting to keep a LATEX document on hand and consistently reproduce an identical DVI file from it, on the fly; or for someone wanting to shield a document during the final stages of its production cycle from unexpected side effects of routine upgrades to the TEX system.

while in latexrelease (global rollback behaviour)

This may be used, for example, to share a document between co-workers using different LaTeX releases, or to protect a document from being affected by system updates.

I focused my attention only on one task that these two packages do. Because, in Python this feature is extremely useful when you share your project.
So, as a LaTeX (well, I always use LuaLaTeX) user, which package is more suitable to "freeze" packages and kernel? IMO, latexrelease but I'm not sure. Maybe other packages exist that I don't know.

latexrelease won't necessarily freeze packages. Some packages might test and offer different behaviour based on the release, but that's far from universal practise.

If you want reproducible builds, I'd go for a container, e.g. https://islandoftex.gitlab.io/community/projects/docker/
